# strange logs in /var/log/messages

Tags: logs, virtual-machine

My `/var/log/messages` contain lots of messages like this:

```
Jan 22 05:45:05 vm kernel: hdc: drive_cmd: status=0x41 { DriveReady Error }
Jan 22 05:45:05 vm kernel: hdc: drive_cmd: error=0x04 { AbortedCommand }
Jan 22 05:45:05 vm kernel: ide: failed opcode was: 0xec
```

I do not even have `hdc` on my system. What can be the cause of them?

My system is `2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive is likely reacting to being [probed by smartd](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.linux.setup/browse_thread/thread/55c3e12d60f9498f).  If so, then there is no real problem.  Check smartd.conf and see if the /dev/hdc is mentioned there in a line that's not commented out.

Comment: Well, there is DEVICESCAN -H -m root which probably scans all devices. I have read the thread you linked and I still do not know what the error means. But thanks to you I know what causes it.

Answer (score 3):

It's your IDE based CD-ROM.

Check out what your CD-ROM points to:

```
ls -l /dev/cdrom
```

Check what IDE devices you have attached to your computer:

```
ls -al /dev/hd?
```

If your machine has freshly or recently booted you can check dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep -i hdc
```

Comment: You are right `ls -l /dev/cdrom` shows /dev/cdrom -> hdc. But could you tell me what the problem actually is with it?

Comment: For some reason something called or checked your CD-ROM. If there wasn't a disc in the drive then it reported a failure to sense that there was a disk in there.